# split full name into first and last name for Rest data

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

A www form provides my cgi script with a full name for the credit card information.  The PayPal Rest API wants a first_name and last_name.  If there are more than two 'words' in the full name, then what is the way to submit the information?  I want to avoid declined cc payments.

Say, given

full_name="Mr. I M Testy".

Should I submit

first_name="Mr. I M",
last_name="Testy"

Or what?

Where is the guidance on the Paypal rest documentation?

Comment: do you get any error ?

Comment: I have not gotten any errors.  But I have not released my code yet, either. My best guess is to put only the last word in the last_name value, and put the rest in first name.  But, someone must know what the real answer is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that seems to work best, in the sandbox, is to split the words given for card holder name into last name and everything else.

ex. "John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt" would be split into

last_name: 'Schmidt'

first_name: 'John Jacob Jingleheimer'

And that is how I would submit it.  If the cardholder goes by one name that is the last name and I submit no first_name parameter at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add them to the end of the first name as you are doing or before last name. There is no convention that is enforced via REST APIs. So as long as you are consistent on your end about how you handle names, the APIs should not stand in your way.

Comment: Thank you, Avi.  I'm not sure I understand, it's not that I need to be consistent in my own behavior, is it?  I have to be consistent with what the credit card processors need for verification, right?

Comment: By consistancy, I only meant that the REST API would not complain regardless of your naming convention. (i.e. either space separated first and middle names in first_name and last name for last_name field or other way around). Either way should be fine, you can choose what convention you want to use.

Comment: Did that sufficiently answer your question?